# Background Image is not showing up on Gosu

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I am right now trying to create a game in Gosu and Ruby. I am running into an issue where a background image is not showing up in my code.  I am getting no errors but whenever I launch the application I am getting a black screen and I stumped as to why, can anyone please help?

```
require 'gosu'
require_relative 'player'
require_relative 'enemy'
require_relative 'bullet'
require_relative 'eb_bullet'
require_relative 'explosion'

class SectorFive < Gosu::Window
 WIDTH = 800
 HEIGHT = 600
 ENEMY_FREQUENCY = 0.03
 ENEMY_BULLET_FREQUENCY = 0.009
 def initialize
  super(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
  self.caption = "Sector Five"
  @background_image = Gosu::Image.new('images/start_screen.png')
end


def draw
 @background_image.draw(0,0,0)
end
end
window = SectorFive.new
window.show
```

Comment: Hi, could there be anything wrong with the png itself? Also, are you running this on windows? I've just run this on my mac with a random png from the internet - worked fine but I don't have your various requires, could be something there causing it perhaps?

Comment: I thought that I picked this off of someones github and yes I am running this on windows

Answer (score 1):

Your indenting is awkward and you need an `update` method in your SectorFive class, e.g.

```
require 'gosu'
#require_relative 'player'
#require_relative 'enemy'
#require_relative 'bullet'
#require_relative 'eb_bullet'
#require_relative 'explosion'

class SectorFive < Gosu::Window
#  ENEMY_FREQUENCY = 0.03
#  ENEMY_BULLET_FREQUENCY = 0.009

  def initialize(width=800, height=600)
    @width     = width
    @height    = height
    super width, height, false    # <-- fullscreen = false
    self.caption = "Sector Five"
    @background_image = Gosu::Image.new('images/start_screen.png')
  end

  def update                      # <-- updates @60hZ; game logic goes here
  end

  def draw
    @background_image.draw(0,0,0)
  end

end

window = SectorFive.new
window.show
```

...with a subdirectory `images` and an portable network graphics file named "startup_screen.png", this script loads an 800x600 gosu window with the png file justified to the upper left-hand corner.